# Swift - Can you create conditional vars?

Tags: swift, if-statement, struct, var

Is it possible to change a var's value conditionally?

I have a menu structure that needs to appear differently depending on whether some calculations have taken place, active = true/false.

Below is what I would LIKE to write but clearly you can't put a conditional within a var statement. How could I achieve this?

```
struct Results: Identifiable {
var id = UUID().uuidString
var category: String
var active: Bool
}

var results = [
    if GlobalVariables.calculated == true {
        Results(category: "Results", active: true)
    } else {
        Results(category: "Results", active: false)
    }
]
```

Comment: How about using a [computed property](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/properties/#Computed-Properties)? Looks like it would be appropriate in this situation. You want `results` to have the appropriate `active` value, every time you access it, right?

Comment: You have declared it as an mutable array, does that mean that you want to append more values?

Comment: Mutable = no - thanks - will change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this simple case, you could try using a ternary, like this:

```
var results = [ GlobalVariables.calculated ? Results(category: "Results", active: true) : Results(category: "Results", active: false)
]

print("---> results: \(results) \n")
```

Comment: The syntax I ended up using was: (GlobalVariables.calculated ? true : false)

Answer (score 0):

A better choice is to use a computed property

```
var results : [Results] {
     return [Results(category: "Results", active: GlobalVariables.calculated)]
}
```

or, if `results` is supposed to be initialized only once, a `lazy` property

```
lazy var results : [Results] = {
     return [Results(category: "Results", active: GlobalVariables.calculated)]
}()
```

Side note: Types which are primarily used in an array should be named in singular form.

Comment: `calculated` may be an optional in the op.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini If so append `== true`

Comment: I simplified the array for the purposes of the question. There are 25 rows and 6 columns/elements. Should I still follow this approach?

Comment: If the configuration can change use the computed property, otherwise the lazy instantiated property.

Comment: Because the var array is large these approaches are unwieldy. Instead I went for a simpler technique which is to load the base vars and then do a conditional test in the .onAppear and if false change the required values as required, e.g. results[25].active = false.  This works and the values are changed correctly but the results of these attributes on screen haven't changed. Is there a way to get the new values reloaded in the view? Tried changing everything to a @State var but that is going to require a lot of refactoring.

Comment: As you are talking about SwiftUI – which was not clear initially – calculate the stuff in a view model.

Comment: I was expecting the answer to be more complex than it was. This syntax was what I sued in the end: (GlobalVariables.calculated ? true : false). Thank you for your help.